# Swift compiler - code generation

Tags: xcode, swift, bridging-header

I want to configure bridging header file, but my `Xcode` doesn't have an `objective-c` bridging header section.

[image: my Xcode build settings image is here]

Comment: Create an Objective-C file. Xcode should ask you if you want to add a bridging header and configure build settings automatically.

Comment: I already create new objective-c file but Xcode didn't ask me anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create an Objective-C .h suppose you call it bridging-header.h
You include all the Objective-C .h that you need for your project in it.
Then you have to go in your project navigator select your project. In the Target section you also have to select your project, then you select 'build settings'. Scroll down to the bottom in 'Swift compiler - code generation ' you need to put 'yes' to 'install Objective-C bridging header' and in 'objective- bridging header' you need to put : 'prjectName/bridging-header.h'
[Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html)

Comment: I already created header file in my swift project but Xcode didn't ask me anything  like this "Would you like  to configure an Objective-C bridging header?" and also don't have  install objective-c bridging header section.  I don't understand what's wrong

Comment: I'm so sorry bro it's my bad. i was clicked basic tag because that sections are hided.